# Few beginner set theory questions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have two problems in beginner set theory, and one I am having lot of trouble with, one I am not sure and would want to know if is it correct.

The first one I am having trouble with is

(1)

Suppose $B \subset A_{1}$ and $B \subset A_{2}$

if $$|A_{1}\setminus B|=|A_{2} \setminus B|$$

Then what can be said about the statement $|A_{1}|=|A_{2}|$

Either it is always true, or true if $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ are finite but not in general, or it could be false regardless of if they are finite or not.

I keep trying to come up with counter examples but I don't seem to get anywhere, I know the definition of cardinality we are using implies there is a bijection between the sets. To me, it seems like this would be true when finite, I am having trouble finding out fersure. I think when infinite, we could probably come up with an example but I am again not sure. I also don't know how to prove such statements. If I did have to pick right now I would probably choose True if finite but not always.

Update;   But how I can say there a bijection between the set without b implies a bijection between the A?

Comment: Do you mean $A \setminus B$ and not $A/B$? (You can draw $\setminus$ using `\setminus`)

Answer (score -1):

(1)

> No, that claim is false. Take $A_1 = \mathbb{N}, A_2 = \mathbb{R}, B = \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ (I'll assume you know $|\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{Q}| = \aleph_0 < \aleph_1 = |\mathbb{R}|$

Oops, sorry, I missed the part where $B \subset A_1, A_2$

Then it's true, because $|X| = |Y| \iff \exists f:X \rightarrow Y$ where $f$ is bijective, and it's easy to extend the bijection on $B$ to get $f':A_1 \rightarrow A_2$ bijective.

(2) To prove equality between sets you should always proceed by showing  double inclusion, i.e. $$X = Y \iff X \subset Y \land Y \subset X$$

Comment: If only $\aleph_1=|\Bbb R|$...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Let's make it $c$

Comment: Which claim is true ? Because there are 3 choices, true for any finitie and infinite? and so is my second not correct?

Comment: @PersonaA "Then what can be said about the statement $|A1|=|A2|$" It can be said that it's true, simply because you can extend the bijection to $B$ (taking the identity, for example).

Comment: What? I don't follow. I understand bijections and such. I do not understand what Is meant by extend the bijection to B..

Comment: @PersonaA suppose $f:A_1 \setminus B \rightarrow A_2 \setminus B$ is a bijection between the two sets. Then we can define $f':A_1 \rightarrow A_2$ such that $f'(x) = f(x)$ if $x \in A_1 \setminus B$ and $f'(x) = x$ if $x \in B$. Then that is trivially a bijection, which **extends** $f$'s domain

Comment: Thanks, that I understand. How about the second question tho? Is it right?

Comment: Can you please tell me what was meant about your comment about the second part? I still do not know if you meant it was right or not